# how set pages number gotten from responce as a number, not as array in PaginationJS

Tags: javascript, pagination

I use 
[paginationjs](http://pagination.js.org)

how make paginationjs work with a pages quanitity, not an array?

from the server i receive next data:

```
content: (2) [{…}, {…}]
number: 2
numberOfElements: 2
size: 2
sort: {unsorted: false, sorted: true, empty: false}
totalElements: 38
totalPages: 19
```

my pagination configs:

```
$('#abc').pagination({
  pageSize: 10,
  pageNumber: 2,
  dataSource: 'http://localhost:9090/admin/api/modelType/page?pageNumber=2&pageSize=2',
  locator: 'totalPages',
  totalNumberLocator: (data) => data.totalPages,
}
```

i cannot change data from number to the array in the responce body. Is there any other way to make it work without providing hardcode value or array?

Also i tried to locate the pages quanity number with 
`locator: 'totalPages'` but of cause it says totalPages is not an array.

Thanks

here is the query:

[image]

the parsed received object:

[image]

the error "locator is not an array":

[image: Pagination: dataSource.totalPages must be an Array]

**EDIT**
If i remove locator i got another error saying `Pagination: "locator" is incorrect.`

[image: Pagination: "locator" is incorrect.]

Comment: How do you get your data from the server? And why don't you use your pagination after you get those data?

Comment: pageSize is responsible for display specified number of elements on a page, but i need to set the quantity of all pages. It's analog of static way of page creation:
```formatResult: function(data) {
        var pagesAnchors = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < totalPages; i++) {
            pagesAnchors.push(i);
        }
        return pagesAnchors;
    }```

Comment: i use ajax built-in method to manage the link as it's shown in my question

Comment: >"And why don't you use your pagination after you get those data"

i try to manage pagination right after the success

Comment: Try to use `Promise` like `getData().then(response => // set your pagination // )`

Comment: that's a problem, because i have to use genuine ajax method from paginationJS because it also containes url parsers and prepares links for next pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get back a response from the server looking like:

```
{
  content: [{…}, {…}]
  number: 2
  numberOfElements: 2
  size: 2
  sort: {unsorted: false, sorted: true, empty: false}
  totalElements: 38
  totalPages: 19
}
```

... right?

Then you want to pass the 'totalElements' to the pagination-configuration, right?!?
 ...if thats what you like, then i think according to the [documentation](http://pagination.js.org/) (see "Asynchronous & Dynamic total number") that can be solved like follows:

```js
$('#abc').pagination({
  pageSize: 10,
  dataSource: '/admin/api/modelType/page?pageNumber=2&pageSize=2',

//how can i set totalNumber from a responce data, not a hardcoded value?
  totalNumberLocator: function(response) { 
    return response.totalElements;
  },
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok you need to pass the amount of **totalElements** in the totalNumberLocator not the number of totalPages. And delete the locator: 'totalPages'. See the code above i already corected that.

Comment: i though the same but first: it asks to specify the ***locator***, second: if i specify it as ```{locator: totalPages}``` it throws an error because it exects an array, not just a plain number ```Uncaught Error: Pagination: dataSource.totalPages must be an Array.```

Comment: Please let me see more code... sample response from ```/admin/api/modelType/page?pageNumber=2&pageSize=2``` would be helpful

Comment: i updated the question, check the sceenshots please

Comment: i tried to remove just **locator ** from the configs but it doesnt work without it throwing another error. I added the pic to my question